# Android Webview can run a JSP?

Tags: java, android, jsp, webview, android-webview

Thats my logcat, i dont know why my web system dont load on webview:

> 01-24 11:47:45.907
>   12101-12223/ews.sys.mobile_portal_do_professorW/cr_CrashFileManager:/data/user/0/ews.sys.mobile_portal_do_professor/cache/WebView/Crash
>   Reports does not exist or is not a directory 01-24 11:47:46.020
>   3370-3410/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityStopTrigger 
>   01-24 11:47:46.045 671-671/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary
>   event log: overflow. 01-24 11:47:46.159
>   12101-12101/ews.sys.mobile_portal_do_professor I/chromium:
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
>   source: http://177.154.128.149:8080/ews/index.jsp (6)

Thats my webview class:

```
 private android.webkit.WebView wv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.portal_do_aluno);

        wv = (android.webkit.WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);




       wv.loadUrl("http://177.154.128.149:8080/ews/index.jsp");
```

Answer (score 1):

If i load your url, i get a malformed HTML document :

It begins with

```
</head>
```

It contains incorrect javascript (no ending semicolon), i suspect it's the latter as stated by the error (line 6 corresponds to the alert statement):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
alert(navigator.appName);
if(navigator.appName!='Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
    alert('NAVEGADOR NÃO INDICADO!\nO Navegador que você está usando não é o adequado para a visualização desse site.\nEste site foi projetado para ser visualizado com Microsoft Internet Explorer, versão 6 ou superior');
</script>
```

Some browsers will try to correct that and read your HTML/js, others like android's WebViewClient will simply fail.

Comment: I fix the jsp html errors, but now the error changed on logcat: